# Echo function does not display

Tags: php, html

I tries validating the form values by using the echo function but it did not work it didn't display on the top like how i expected can you help me.
this is the php code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $username=isset($_POST["username"]);
    $password=isset($_POST["password"]);
    echo "your name is".$username."and your password is ".$password;
}
?>
```

the form html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form.php" methode="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your name">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password"/><br>
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get rid of `isset()`. You're using it wrong.

Comment: nitpick: `echo` is not a function. it's a language construct. and `isset()` returns a boolean true/false, which you then try to echo out. It does **NOT** return whatever value you're testing in the variable.

Comment: but without the isset() funtion I can not know if the submit button has been checked ! it should be true to execut the construction

Comment: get rid of  `isset` on your `$username` and `$password`

Answer (score 0):

Using isset checks that there is a value for the thing you specify. In this case the 'username' index in the $_POST superglobal. So writing 
`$username = isset($_POST["username"])`
is returning a boolean, not the string value you are trying for. If you want the string value of $_POST['username'], use a ternary around the isset like this:

```
$username = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : 'Some flavor of not set error';
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form, the method attribute is mistakenly spelled with an "e" at the end. Once you change it to "method" your post should start working.